# *ngFor's rendered order is unreliable after an HTTP/JSONP call?

Tags: http, angular, jsonp, ngfor

I make a JSONP call using information from an array of "keys", which are in a particular order. I want the resulting new array, to be the same order as the source array of keys. This happens sometimes, but not always.

I have tried forEach, for loop, a simple array with just the key values, and an array with the field "name" followed by the key value. No idea why I can't get a consistent order. Following is with a simple array and just key values.

```
 /*separate defining class*/
 export class ArrayObjectItem {
  city: string;

constructor(city: string) {

this.city = city;
 }

  }
  /**/

  /*Below follows the code inside the main bootstrapped/rendering component*/

 names: [] = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5'];
 arraytorender: Array<ArrayObjectItem>[] = [];

this.names.forEach(name => {
  this.aJSONPservice.getData(name).subscribe(response => {
    const objectinarray = new ArrayObjectItem("null");
    objectinarray.city = response.city;
 this.arraytorender.push(objectinarray);

 });
 });
```

In the view of the main component:

```
<div *ngFor="#item of arraytorender">
 {{item.city}}
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see how this can be related to HTTP/JSONP. Can you create a Plunker that allows to reproduce?

Comment: Just because the http requests are sent out in a particular order there is no reason to assume the responses will come back in the same order.  They will be pushed into `arraytorender` in the order the requests completed not the order they were issued.

Comment: Hey Gunter, please see this codepen. Not exactly the same program structure, but you will see that each ArrayObjectItem has the same city from the HTTP call, and a different name from "names". Instead of Same Location Name1 and then Same Location Name2, etc., the "arraytorender" is in any arbitrary order. http://codepen.io/webdev689/full/aNYjRM.

Comment: So the question is not about `ngFor` not rendering the elements in the order they appear in the `arraytorender`?

Comment: It is exactly about that only. The resulting list should always be "City Name1", "City Name2", "City Name3"...because the keys are ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"...]. The previous arraytorender was based on a hypothetical HTTP call where each name got back a unique city, so like ["CityfromName1", "CityfromName2", "CityfromName3"...]. But regardless, it never renders correctly in the template, in that correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*ngFor` does the right thing. The array is just not sorted.
If you sort it you get the desired result:

```ts
  ngOnInit():any {
    this.names.forEach(name => {
      this._cityService.getCity().subscribe(response => {
        const objectinarray = new ArrayObjectItem("null", "null");
        objectinarray.city = response.city;
        objectinarray.namefromkeys = name;
        this.arraytorender.push(objectinarray);
        this.arraytorender.sort((a,b) => {
          if(a.namefromkeys == b.namefromkeys) {
            return 0;
          }
          if(a.namefromkeys > b.namefromkeys) {
            return 1;
          }
          return -1;
        });
      });
    })
  }
```

Comment: Your revised solution works - thank you very much! I am a new user here, so can't upvote or give you the best answer for the first correct solution (the one after you is also right).

Comment: Don't worry. Thanks for the feeback :)

Comment: If this solved your problem it would be great if you could accept an answer to indicate this problem is solved (checkmark below the up/down-vote buttons).

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort array after each push, since responses come in random order:

```
this.arraytorender.push(objectinarray);
this.arraytorender.sort((a,b)=>{
  if (a.city < b.city)
    return -1;
  else if (a.city > b.city)
    return 1;
 else 
    return 0;
});
```

You might need to force change trigger:

```
this.arraytorender = this.arraytorender.concat();
```

Comment: I did not need to use the concat() stuff, but the sort logic is right. Thanks very much. Sorry, as a new user I can't upvote. Someone answered before you with the same response, too.